# Stopping "TextBox_Change" event from executing if called by code

Tags: vba, textbox, userform

I have a userform which contains a `TextBox` object named `myTextBox`.

The text inside the object can be changed *either* by the user *or* by the code. There's a "onChange" procedures attached to the textbox:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Change()
    'do some stuffs
End Sub
```

I would like the event to be processed **only when is the user changing the text**, but not the code. I had thought about adding an Optional parameter like the following:

```
Private Sub myTextBox_Change(Optional isCode As Boolean)
    If isCode = False Then
        'do some stuffs
    End If
End Sub
```

but this is not really helpful because I cannot pass the `isCode = True` when changing the name programmatically, like this:

```
myForm.myTextBox = "new text"
```

Does anyone have an idea on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way (perhaps not the right way?) would be to declare a global variable to use in the same way as your IsCode Boolean. Set it to true during your code block so the textbox_change event knows code is processing in the background, and then set back to false when that code has finished.

Put this at the top of a normal module (won't work in a form module)

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Global IsCode As Boolean
```

and then in the code you're running just set `IsCode=true` as required.

Comment: Not a bad idea, I had also thought about a property of the form `isCode` to set `True` or `False` depending on if I want the event handler to be fired,  but will wait a bit more to see if someone knows some way to deactivate the event-handler in VBA (it would be cleaner I think).

Comment: Finally going to use your solution, I preferred not to overload the form with useless properties and nobody has told me yet about how to remove the change listener! Thank you